# mysql query when input contains more characters then db column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a mysql query such that the search string that a user enters is the value in the database plus up to two additional characters (from a subset of 0-5 and a-b).

I had originally started doing the query using the mysql INSTR function, such that my query would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE INSTR(<user_input>, name) = 1;
```

But this obviously doesn't check what the additional characters are, or how many there are, so depending on the existing rows, it doesn't return the correct values. How can I write the query to do that?

For example, if I have the following rows in my DB:

```
Name: ABCD
Name: LMNO
Name: A
```

If the user sends ABCD, or ABCD1, I want it to return the first row (using the INSTR method I was originally using, it would return both the first and last rows), but if they send A2B, it would return the last one.

Comment: My opinion is you are better off using `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'BLAH';` where you construct `BLAH` from `user_input` yourself.  BTW, be aware of the dangers of allowing unsanitized user_input in your DB queries.... https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

use
`where '%'||field_name||'%' like ABCD1;`

and then you pick max length.